# how does internalresourceviewresolver work?

Tags: spring-mvc

how does  internalresourceviewresolver  work, when my controller class does not return a modelandview object? how does it map to views?

here is the code snippet from the controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Map<String, Object>> getabc() 
{
    return jdbcDa.abc();
}
```

and here is the code snippet from dispatcher servlet:

```
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: AFAIK this case will not be using `InternalResourceViewResolver` as the response is not a `ModelAndView` and is annotated with `@ResponseBody` it will be processed by one of the available `MessageConverter` like `StringConverter` / `Jackson` etc

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks a lot.. could you please throw some light on how it gets mapped to a view in this case? how does `@ResponseBody` annotation work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal view resolver is not involved here, you have annotated with `@ResponseBody` and the method does not return a string/view name.

The returned data doesn't get mapped to a view. It is converted to json or xml depending on the content type of original request.

A method annotated with `@ResponseBody` would normally be called asynchronously using javascript, the returned data would then, in a web app, be added to a specific part of the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Your method was annotated by `@ResponseBody`, so the method will convert the `List<Map<String, Object>>` to JSON, and wouldn't map to the view.

If you want to map the date to view, you can use AJAX request date from this interface `@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, and use Javascript to show the date on the view. Just like this fragment:

```
$.getJSON('/abc', function (date) {
     var s = "";
     $.each(date, function (i, obj) {
          //use javascript to add date to variable s
     });
     //add s to view element
     $("#tag-list").append(s);
});
```